# Why does 11 / 1 % 2 / 11 give a different answer than (11 / 1) % (2 / 11) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arithmetic-expressions

I was just playing around with arithmetic operators in Python, when I encountered a strange thing of Python arithmetic.

```
>>> (11 / 1) % (2 / 11)
0.0909090909090906
>>> 11 / 1 % 2 / 11
0.09090909090909091
```

Why is there a difference in both these answers? The mathematics is the same, then why a difference in the result?

Comment: This is like asking why `(1 + 2) * 3` gives other result than `1 + 2 * 3`

Comment: @DeepSpace I guess this one is not that simple. I would appreciate if you could apply this same rule to the question above.....

Comment: It is just as simple. Parenthesis change order of operation

Comment: @coderboy Since `%` and divide `/` have the same precedence it is evaluated left to right. While in DeepSpaces example `*` has higher precedence than `+`.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

We expect you to look up operator precedence; this is not a Stack Overflow issue.

Answer (score 3):

`/` and `%` have the same [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).  So `11 / 1 % 2 / 11` is evaluated left-to-right, i.e. `((11 / 1) % 2) / 11`.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the left-to-right computation but couldn't apply it on the value.